# ElasticSearch No Node Available Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I was indexing around 70,000 records. Normally it takes around 1 to 2 minutes to bulk index. But this time it took more than 10 minutes and an exception was thrown from C# Nest Client.
Does anybody experience the below. Also to note that I set Index Refresh Interval as 30s.

ElasticSearch C# Nest Client. Below are the exception details:

```
Elasticsearch.Net.Exceptions.MaxRetryException occurred
HResult=-2146233088

Message=Unable to perform request: 'POST @indexName/_bulk' on any
    of the nodes after retrying 0 times.

Source=Elasticsearch.Net
StackTrace:
    at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.RetryRequestAsync[T]
            (TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Uri baseUri, Int32 retried, 
            Exception e) in
     c:\Projects\NEST\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\Transport.cs:line 344
InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help you, but I had similar issue in 2 node cluster. I've was adding synonyms and setup the file for only master machine. I completely forgot to copy it over to 2nd node. This was causing the error above for me when creating new index that depended on that synonym file. Which totally makes sense.

After I added synonym file and restarted 2nd node, everything went back to normal.